# Fail2ban - send email with msmtp

Tags: fail2ban

How do I set up fail2ban to send emails using msmtp?

I tried changing the `mta = sendmail` line to `mta = msmtp` and the `action = %(action_)s` line to `action = %(action_mwl)s`.

I think `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/msmtp-whois-lines.conf` file, but I'm not sure what to put in it.

I can normally send mail from the command line with `echo -e "Subject: subject\nMessage contents" | msmtp recipient@hotmail.com` without a password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is the following:

First thing is to copy all `action.d/sendmail-*.conf` files to `action.d/msmtp-*.conf` files:

```
for file in /etc/fail2ban/action.d/sendmail*.conf; do cp "$file" "${file/sendmail/msmtp}"; done
```

Next step is to change the occurrences of `before = sendmail` to `before = msmtp` in the `action.d/msmtp-*.conf` files:

```
sed -i 's/before = sendmail/before = msmtp/' /etc/fail2ban/action.d/msmtp-*.conf
```

This will correct the references to other sendmail configuration files like `before = sendmail-common.conf`.

Followed by changing all occurrences of `sendmail -f <sender>` to `msmtp` in `action.d/msmtp-*.conf`:

```
sed -i 's/sendmail -f <sender>/msmtp/p' /etc/fail2ban/action.d/msmtp-*.conf
```

This will correct the lines where `sendmail` is called like `Fail2Ban | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f <sender> <dest>`.

The final step is changing the `mta = msmtp` in the `action.d/jail.conf` file. 
Then reload fail2ban to test whether these modifications work.

Another thing to keep in mind is the user context of fail2ban with respect to the msmtp configuration. If you have a local `msmtprc` file configured, it might not be applied when fail2ban tries to run msmtp due to other user context. In that case, configure msmtp with a global configuration, or create a separate configuration for the user that runs fail2ban.

Comment: I also had to run something like `sudo sed -i 's/\/usr\/sbin\/msmtp/\/usr\/bin\/msmtp/' /etc/fail2ban/action.d/msmtp*.conf`, and there was also an msmtp.conf file which I changed

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have enough reputation to comment directly under *Lambert*'s extremly helpfull answer, I will add my thought here:

As *texasflood* pointed out in their comment, you need to run

```
sudo sed -i 's/\/usr\/sbin\/sendmail/\/usr\/bin\/msmtp/' /etc/fail2ban/action.d/msmtp*.conf
```

as well [mark the **sendmail** instead of texasflood's **msmtp** ! - probably just a typo on their side].

And you might need to add **sudo** in front of **cp** or **sed** in order to get it to work correctly.